# how to read any length of string?

Tags: assembly

i'm new to assembly language and am stuck with a dilemma. how do i ask for a string user input and read it with unknown length? currently i only know how to ask for user input and read with a limited length, like...

```
      .data
input db 24 dup ("$")
      .code
      mov input, 22
      lea dx, input
      mov ah, 0ah
      int 21h
```

i was wondering if it is possible to ask for user input without worrying about the length...if it is possible, could you please show & explain the process/code on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delegate the input process to the OS you'll always have some length restriction to deal with. DOS uses some 255 bytes limit.

But even if you wrote yourself an input routine you would still have to worry about how much memory you are prepared to spend storing the characters.

Answer (score 1):

In DOS you can read input string of (almost) arbitrary length on file level with function AH=3Fh,
see Interrupt list http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2783.htm

```
MOV DX, OFFSET input ; Memory where you want the string be read to.
MOV CX,24 ; Number of bytes allocated for the string (maximal possible length).
MOV BX,0 ; Standard handle for system input (usually the keyboard).
MOV AH,3Fh ; DOS function "READ FROM FILE OR DEVICE"
INT 21h ; Waits until ENTER pressed (character 0Dh). Returns AX=number of bytes read.
```

Answer (score 0):

As one of the options, you could use a loop with BIOS int 16h fn 0 to wait for a key press, then check which key has been pressed and process accordingly.

Something like

```
  ;
  ; ES:DI points to input buffer
  ;
_do:
  ;
  ; wait key press
  ;
  mov ah, 0
  int 0x16
  cmp al, 13  ;ENTER pressed?
  jz _end
  ;
  ; display char
  ;
  mov ah, 0x0e
  mov bh, 0
  int 0x10
  ;
  ; save char to buffer
  ;
  stosb
  jmp _do
_end:
  ...
```

Comment: Careful, don't reinvent `gets()`. It is easily done, but is considered a Very Bad Idea!

Comment: Don't write a function which accepts a pointer to a buffer without a length limit.  This is why `gets()` is deprecated in ISO C, and can't be used safely unless you already know the data you're reading.  In your code, by holding down a key a user can eventually overflow any buffer, unless your buffer is `es:0..ffff`, so DI wraps around harmlessly.